# SFML 2.0 Linux installation issue

Tags: linux, sfml

I am trying without sucess to install SFML 2.0 on a Ubuntu 15.10.

I follow the tutorial:http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-linux.php . 
I  downloaded the Linux archive from the link http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.0/. After that I extracted the archive to /usr/local/ directory on my computer. I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o -L/usr/local/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

I get

```
fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory.
```

When compiling with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o -I/usr/local/include -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-graphics
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-window
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-system
```

When I compile the code simply with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

I am getting:

```
fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory.
```

I tried the`sudo make install` in the SFML2.0 directory, but all I get is `install: missing file operand`
It is really important to install the 2.0 version of SFML. I thought about installing the SFML form the packet manager, but with `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev` I would get a newer version of SFML and not the 2.0.
Can you tell what should I do to install properly SFML 2.0 on my machine?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory.`
definitely means that your extraction process failed to copy the directory structure over correctly. The folder `SFML-2.0` should not be in `/usr/local/` .

1. Extract SFML-2.0 into a directory `tar xvf SFML*.tar.bz2`
2. Cd to that directory `cd SFML-2.0`
3. Manually copy the contents the directories in `SFML-2.0/` (`include` `lib` and `share`) into their respective directories in `/usr/local`

   1. `sudo cp -r share/SFML/ /usr/local/share/`
   2. `sudo cp -r lib/* /usr/local/lib/`
   3. `sudo cp -r include/SFML /usr/local/include/`

(Note this will make a mess out of `lib`)

Try to recompile main after verifying that the directory `SFML-2.0/include/SFML` is now located at `/usr/local/include/SFML`, etc